# Create dynamic components at once using a for-loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to add data to a dynamic component from the parent component

For example:

Let's take a number as the data which I want to pass to the dynamic component.

**the o/p of this snippet is :**

Welcome parent message!

Welcome 5

Welcome 5

Welcome 5

Welcome 5

Welcome 5

**the expected o/p should be** :

Welcome parent message!

Welcome 1

Welcome 2

Welcome 3

Welcome 4

Welcome 5

```js
let dynamicComponent = {
      template: `
        <p>Welcome {{ msg2 }}</p>
      `,
      props:['msg'],
      data () {
        return {
          msg2: this.msg
        }
      },
    }
    
    const App = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data(){
      return{
       parentMsg:'parent message',
       components: [
          dynamicComponent
        ],
      }
      },
    
      methods: {
        add () {
        for(let i=1;i<6;i++){
        this.parentMsg = i;
          this.components.push(dynamicComponent)
          }
        },
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <template v-for="(component, index) in components">
      <component :msg="parentMsg" :is="component" :key="index"></component>
    </template>
    <button @click="add()">Add Component</button>
    </div>
```

The issue comes when I want the components at once using for-loop
all the components have the same data i.e that '5'
and I am not able to understand why is this happening
I tried by using immediately invoking function expression in the for-loop but it seems that also isn't working.

Comment: You are adding 5 components at once in a for loop. That's why you see all messages at once. If you want one message at a time, then you should add one component at a time.

Comment: @sthotakura I guess my question wasn't very clear, so updated it, please see the expected o/p and the actual o/p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating `parentMsg` and adding a new component in a for loop. Vue updates the DOM after the for loop is finished. By the time, the for loop is finished your `parentMsg` value would be `5`. That's why, you are seeing all `Welcome 5`.

The way to achieve what you are trying is by `scheduling` addition of components in Vue's `$nextTick` callback funciton.

I have updated your code to below to get the desired result:

```
methods: {
    add () {
      this.addOneItem(1);
    },
    addOneItem(i) {
      if(i >= 6) return;
      this.parentMsg = i++
      this.components.push(Try)
      this.$nextTick(() => this.addOneItem(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Here, first I am adding one component, and then scheduling the next component to be added in the `$nextTick` callback.

You can read more about `$nextTick` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this

```
:msg="parentMsg"
```

All the dynamic components have the prop `msg` bound to `parentMsg`, this binding. To explain just a little, they all share the same parentMsg, when it changes from say 1 to 2, it changes everywhere it is bound, and so on until it gets to 5. What you want to do is use index instead of parentMsg like this

```
:msg="index"
```

Comment: nope, as I am returning an object for every component (in data) so that the components do not share a reference .  data () {
        return {
          msg2: this.msg
        }
      },

Comment: @Nirman let me put it this way, you are rendering the dynamic components fro  'this.components', which is in the same data() as parentMsg. Now, your v-for is in the root, parentMsg is also in/on the root. And thus all the dynamic components are referencing the same varaible parentMsg.

Comment: @Nirman note, :msg="parentMsg" means bind msg to parentMsg not copy the current value from parentMsg. Thus, when the value in parentMsg changes, the changes reflects everywhere parentMsg is bound to

Comment: if I had not returned the data as an object this would have been the case, and also the 'welcome parent message'  would have changed as it was also bing to parentMsg